# Retrieve Report Comments using the Smartsheet API

Tags: smartsheet-api

I can successfully use the Smartsheet API to retrieve Comments from **Sheets**, but I'm struggling to do so for Comments on **Reports**.

I'm stuck at the point of retrieving a Report's Discussions using the `https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/reports/{reportId}?pageSize=10&page=0&include=discussions`. This API call successfully returns the Discussions themselves, but not the entire thread of Comments.

The documentation specifies to use the `GET /sheets/{sheetId}/discussions/{discussionId}?include=comments`, however it seems as though I can only list the Discussions of a **Sheet** and not a **Report** as I don't believe `/reports/{reportId}/discussions` is an endpoint that the Smartsheet API exposes. It also doesn't seem as though the `/reports/{reportId}` endpoint accepts `include=comments` either.

Any thoughts on how I can retrieve the full comments of a Report?

Answer (score 0):

Reports in Smartsheet are always tied to a sheet, so any comment on a report will be shown in the source sheet. You should retrieve the comments from the source sheet for the report you're working in.